# Point cloud in gazebo environment

Tags: ros2, pcl, pointcloud, lidar, gazebo-ignition

I am working on a project whose main objective is to check the sensors that can perceive the environment and implement those in gazebo environment. so i am trying to implement lidar sensor and generate point cloud of the outdoor environment. Can anyone guide me **how to generate a point cloud of an outdoor environment in Ignition Gazebo Fortress**?

Comment: Please edit your post and tell us what you have figured out so far, and what you are stuck on. A simple web search should return many examples of how to configure a lidar sensor in ignition gazebo.

Comment: @Mike973 sorry about not being specific in the pose. Let me elaborate my question. I have a outdoor environment created in gazebo simulation, which at the moment include just human and a square block  as an entity. I have lidar publishing the lidar data and lidar points. i am able to see the points in rviz. Now i want to create a point cloud for the given scenario. or create a .pcd file of the scene. so that i can implement some dnn algo. so the question is : how can i create a .pcd file? Thank your for your response.

Comment: What message type is the lidar node publishing? If it is LaserScan, you're not going to get much of a "cloud" from a 2d lidar and its single plane.

Comment: @Mike973 I am using pointcloud2 msg for 3d lidar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to take a ros2 PointCloud2 message and write it to a .pcd file.

There is a existing ros1/ros2 package called `pcl_ros`. The src code for both is in this [github repo](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl), but I don't know the current status of the port to ros2. This package has a ros node named `pointcloud_to_pcd` that writes PointCloud2 messages into .pcd files.